# How would I convert this into laravel query builder format?

Tags: sql, laravel, join, subquery, query-builder

I have a query that works using regular sql notation but having a hard time converting it to laravel builder notation.

Query:

```
SELECT Course.CourseName
     , SUM(CASE WHEN StudentID <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As InClass
     , Instructor.InstructorFirstName
     , ProgramName
     , SemesterTaught
 FROM program
      JOIN course
        ON program.ProgramID = course.ProgramID
      JOIN (SELECT CourseID
                 , SemesterTaught 
              FROM classtime 
            GROUP BY CourseID, SemesterTaught) AS classtime
        ON course.CourseID = classtime.CourseID
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT InstructorID
                      , CourseID
                      , StudentID 
                   FROM enrolled) AS enrolled
             ON classtime.CourseID = enrolled.CourseID
      LEFT JOIN instructor
             ON enrolled.InstructorID = instructor.InstructorID
GROUP BY CourseName, InstructorFirstName, SemesterTaught, ProgramName
```

What I've tried:

```
DB::table('programs')
->select('courses.CourseName', 'SUM(CASE WHEN StudentID <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS StudentsInClass', 'instructors.InstructorFirstName', 'ProgramName', 'SemesterTaught')
->join('courses', 'programs.ProgramID', '=', 'course.ProgramID')
->join(DB::raw('(SELECT CourseID, SemesterTaught FROM classtimes GROUP BY CourseID, SemesterTaught) AS classtimes'), 'courses.CourseID', '=', 'classtimes.CourseID')
->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT InstructorID, CourseID, StudentID FROM enrolleds) AS enrolled'), 'classtimes.CourseID', '=', 'enrolled.CourseID')
->leftJoin('instructors', 'enrolled.InstructorID', '=', 'instructors.InstructorID')
->groupBy('courses.CourseName', 'instructors.InstructorFirstName', 'SemesterTaught', 'ProgramName')->get();
```

I would like to achieve this query using laravel query builder syntax and try to avoid using DB::raw if possible. I also am trying to figure out how to use the aggregate function in my select cause without getting the "column doesn't exists error."

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer to getting the query to work if anyone in the future see's this:

```
DB::table('programs')
->select('courses.CourseName', DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN StudentID <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StudentsInClass'), 'instructors.InstructorFirstName', 'ProgramName', 'SemesterTaught')
->join('courses', 'programs.ProgramID', '=', 'courses.Program')
->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT CourseID, SemesterTaught FROM class_times GROUP BY CourseID, SemesterTaught) AS classtimes'), 'courses.CourseID', '=', 'classtimes.CourseID')
->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT InstructorID, CourseID, StudentID FROM enrolleds) AS enrolled'), 'classtimes.CourseID', '=', 'enrolled.CourseID')
->leftJoin('instructors', 'enrolled.InstructorID', '=', 'instructors.InstructorID')
->groupBy('courses.CourseName', 'instructors.InstructorFirstName', 'SemesterTaught', 'ProgramName')->get();
```